# How to modify the prefix when I use getServerSideProps (from /_next/data to /login/_next/data)

Tags: next.js

When I use nextjs , from one route to another , I use getServerSideProps , but in the production mode , next get react props from a remote request like /_next/data/***.json
but in my case , I want to modify the url from /_next/data to /login/_next/data .
how can I do?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do that? One way to do so would be to serve the app from a different `basePath`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath.

Comment: Beacuse our system is built as a k8s pod , we use ingress ,  only the request urls start with /login can be dispatched into the next server. Now i use assets prefix , so the static js works fine .But only the /next/data can not work